# How to fix image size in Windows Phone 8.1 grid column?

Tags: xaml, listview, layout, grid, windows-phone-8.1

I have listview with the following grid as an itemtemplate:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

And I have an image as first column content and a text as second. These resources loads from internet and while image is not loaded first column has no width.

How to fix this? Do I need to track image loading progress and replace some placeholder with real image?

Comment: Could set a `MinWidth`, or on your image binding put a `FallbackValue` pointing to a placeholder image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a placeholder or some kind of fallback? If your users can expect an image that's currently still being loaded you should carry some kind of dummy image along with your assets that is displayed while the content is retrieved.

You can set such fallbacks in your XAML code:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image, FallbackValue='Assets/placeholder.png'}" />
```

And I'd also suggest you to include such a mechanism in your code. Just add the path / reference to your dummy image in your standard constructor and replace it with the real one once your image is retrieved from the internet.